# Strip tags from text?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, strip-tags

I have a form. When users submit the data, my script checks the text for php/html with

```
$text1 = strip_tags($text);
```

Then it inserts the data into the database.
But when users submit something like this: "I totally <3 this website", it only inserts: "I totally". How can I fix this?

(I need to remove the tags)

Comment: *sigh* it sounds like you're abusing `strip_tags`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape those characters instead of stripping them out. You can use the [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function to achieve it. For example:

```
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
```

It escapes special characters as HTML entities so they will be properly displayed.

Comment: Why can't you just do it as anyone else and use html-escaped stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You may replace tags by their eqiualents, don't delete it.
Use

`htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure *why* you want to do this, but you can strip out `<` and `>` by doing

```
$stripped = str_replace(array('<', '>'), '', $text);
```

but i would suggest to escape the string instead like this

```
$escaped = htmlspecialchars($text);
// or
$escaped = htmlentities($text);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the correct answer would be to use [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) as noted in other answers, you can always have an array to pre-process the `$text` before stripping out tags.

```php
$search = array('<3', ':<');
$replace = array('&lt;3', ':&lt;');

echo strip_tags(str_replace($search, $replace, $text));
```

Obviously, you'd have to update your array every time you get a new instance of these special cases - so, probably need to think of a proper outcome.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put it into your db, don't use `strip_tags` but the appropriate [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) function or [prepared statements](http://php.net/mysqli_prepare). later, when outputting the content on an html page, use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchar)